# Removing extra characters when reading csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading in serial numbers from csv files and adding each number to a database.  When I read in the data, it looks like this:

```
="TheSerialNumber"
```

How can I make it so the ="" isn't stored when reading in the row?  The data doesn't look like that in the file.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcod
import csv
import os.path
from os import path

for file in os.listdir(directory):
filename = os.fsdecode(file)
with open('mydirectory' + filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    count = 0
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
      print(row[3])
```

Comment: could you cast it into int?

Comment: @Rebin no there are letters and numbers in the serial numbers

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the csv content?

Comment: If it is just a string, can't you use indices? Like, print(row[3][2:-1])

Comment: for fixed length use array indexing like serial[0:5], if variable size use regex

Comment: I could use that but I believe there are some serial numbers that can be a character or two longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use strip()

example:

```
a = '="TheSerialNumber"'

value = a.strip('="')
print(value)
```

output:

```
TheSerialNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions, matching for the word immediately following the first `"`

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcod
import csv
import os.path
from os import path

import re

for file in os.listdir(directory):
filename = os.fsdecode(file)
with open('mydirectory' + filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    count = 0
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        word = re.search(r'(?<==")\w+', row[3])
        print(word)
```

This should return the first word following the `="` in `="serialnum"`
I would read the documentation on the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), as it is very applicable to your situation.